# How to rewrite an URL after adding a trailing slash (.htaccess / mod_rewrite)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not too used to work with htaccess files so I struggled for a while on this one :

I'd like to know how can I rewrite an URL (example.com/foo/bar) to (example.com/index.php?q=/foo/bar) AFTER adding a trailing slash (301 redirect) to the initial URL :

I know how to add the trailing slash alone :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exemple.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

And how to rewrite to index.php :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

But I just can't figure how to do both at the same time...

Any help is more than welcome !

Pierre Fraisse

Comment: Just put both sets of line into one file. No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine on` part. I would however use `^(.+)$`

Comment: Well, that's of course the first thing i tried :) but it doesn't work...
However I noticed that putting the rewrite index.php first make the 301 redirect go to index.php?q=XXX instead of adding a trailing slash...

Comment: The redirect should always come first. Could you explain what did not work? I assume both script are working on their own? I can't really see why it wouldn't work. The only thing I can think of, is that the php script doesn't like it when $_GET['q'] ends with a slash?

Comment: Indeed the 2 scripts are working on their own : the redirect one add the slash but I get a 404 error (of course ^^) and the rewriting one work but i don't have the slash at the end. What doesn't work when they are together is the redirect one. The rewriting is still working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess (I tested it as far as I could):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Just tried it, I guess you almost got it right :
Right now, the rewrite work but the redirect is a bit strange :
When I try example.com/foo/bar it redirects to example.com/www/sourcefolder/foo/bar/ (/www/sourcefolder/ is the absolute path to the document_root of my site)

Comment: Sorry I typed enter before finishing my answer :) Just edited it !

Comment: Oh in fact it's a bit more complicated !
I'm gonna give you some details :
The real absolute path of my site is "homez.398/bonoworl/www/nebulous/"
and I tried with "mysite.com/home" (note as home is the beginning of my absolute path). When I try this one it redirect to mysite.com/homez.398/bonoworl/www/nebulous/home/ but with something else (like foo/bar) it works correctly...

Comment: Ohh that's because `home` is a real folder, and the rule at the beginning says if the request matches a real folder then don't do any rewriting and go straight to it. Did you want the rewrite to be performed with /home or not? I'm still puzzled as to why the system path is showing up.

Comment: What's the DocumentRoot in your webserver conf file?

Comment: Like I said it's really a special case, it just works fine for others url ! I'm gonna mark your answer as correct :) Thanks for your help, I really apreciate !

Comment: No problem :) I have to head out right now, but if you're interested in debugging this I'll be back in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

You have an accepted answer here but I still like to answer this since actual answer is **way more simpler** that running it through multiple (and slow) redirects as in the other answer.

Put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```